# How phpmyadmin shows green square in "Check All" checkbox when all checkboxes are not checked - HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, phpmyadmin

I am wondering how phpmyadmin shows small green square in Check All checkbox when all other checkboxes are not selected. Is there any way to achieve this? I managed to check/uncheck feature but don't know how to put that small square in checkbox. Here is a snaphost to understand what I am asking for -

[image]

See small green square in Check All when one row in phpmyadmin is not being selected.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

Comment: Thanks. Now I came to know about indeterminate state of checkbox after reading above article.